# How can I get a VirtualMachine reference using VMware Java vSphere SDK?

Tags: powershell, powercli, vmware-sdk

I am familiar with using the VMware VIM API in C# using the VMware.Vim.dll provided in the PowerCLI. Now I want to be able to program with this API using Java, but I can't find an equivalent to it. The com.vmware.vim.jar in the vSphere SDK doesn't seem to have all of the classes that are mentioned in the API reference here:

http://www.vmware.com/support/developer/vc-sdk/

Specifically, in Java I can't figure out how to get a VirtualMachine instance. In C#, I can get all virtual machines on a stand alone hypervisor by doing the following:

```
        String serviceUrl = "https://192.168.1.100/sdk/vimService";
        String username = "root";
        String password = "MyPassword";

        VimClient client = new VimClient();
        client.Connect(serviceUrl);
        client.Login(username, password);

        var virtualMachines = client.FindEntityViews(typeof(VirtualMachine), client.ServiceContent.RootFolder, null, null).OfType<VirtualMachine>();
```

How can I get this using Java?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using VMware Infrastructure (vSphere) Java API i.e vijava below code works to find all VM's in inventory.

```
    String serviceUrl = "https://Your IP Address/sdk";
    String username = "root";
    String password = "MyPassword";      
    ServiceInstance si = new ServiceInstance(new URL(serviceUrl), username , password     ,     true);
    Folder rootFolder = si.getRootFolder();
    ManagedEntity[] entities = new InventoryNavigator(rootFolder).searchManagedEntities("VirtualMachine");

    for (ManagedEntity e : entities) {

        vm = (VirtualMachine) e;
        System.out.println("vm=" + vm.getName());
    }
```

OR

http://sourceforge.net/p/vijava/discussion/826592/thread/a6c44685#5b30     ---in cluster environment

Answer (score 2):

I found that the VMware Infrastructure (vSphere) Java API can do this:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/vijava/files/vijava/